# How to change MUI Chip's background color when filled?

Tags: material-ui

I want to change Chip's background color when it's `variants` value is `'filled'` because the default light gray doesn't feel satisfactory.

I read MUI docs and Chip API but it's too complicated for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of Chip's exported [CSS classes](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/chip/#css)

```
import Chip, { chipClasses } from "@mui/material/Chip";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

// ..

const CustomChip = styled(Chip)({
  [`&.${chipClasses.filled}`]: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit hardcore-mcnulty-258q0j]